# How do I perform these basic operations for linked lists in a functional language?

Tags: linked-list, sml

**Conversion of Lists to Linked Lists**

I'm trying to convert a list to a singly linked list (not sure if doubly linked lists are possible anyway) in standard ML. However, I am not sure  how this is done, but will show my attempt so far.

```
datatype 'a mlist = Nil
        | Cons of 'a * 'a mlist ref

fun listToLL [] = Nil
    | listToLL (x::xs) = Cons(x, (ref (listToLL xs)))
```

I have created a linked list over datatype first, but I'm confused by the 'ref' function. I want to avoid making the linked list into a lazy list, so the ref is there for me to explicitly make the next sequence a reference of the previous one only. But the problem is that this function does not make use of the linked list data type at all, and works even if I don't use this linked list definition. So is my implementation actually correct?

As a side question, is the only thing distinguishing linked lists from lazy lists the 'ref' function? Judging from their datatype definitions, this seem to be that way.

**Joining two linked lists together**

```
fun joining (mlpx, mlpy) = 
    case !mlpx of
        Nil => mlpx := mlpy
    |   Cons(_, mlp) => joining(mlp, mlpy)          


fun join (mlpx, mlpy) = 
    let
        val mlp = ref mlpx
    in
        joining(mlp, mlpy);
        !mlp
    end;
```

For the second operation, I'm very confused by the need for `ref` in the second join function at all. When I handle a linked list, do I expect that I handle a reference or do I handle the entire Cons structure that contains the reference from within? I don't get why we can't just use the `joining` function by itself as it seems to be really sufficient. Why is there a need to create a `ref` in the `join` function?

Answer (score 2):

> I have created a linked list over datatype first, but I'm confused by the 'ref' function. I want to avoid making the linked list into a lazy list [...]
>
> [...]
>
> As a side question, is the only thing distinguishing linked lists from lazy lists the 'ref' function?

Lazy lists are quite different, because they require "suspending" a computation, typically by creating a closure (for example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46997808/1031831) for an implementation of lazy lists in SML). Your implementation isn't lazy. The usage of `ref` simply allows mutability.

> But the problem is that this function does not make use of the linked list data type at all, and works even if I don't use this linked list definition. So is my implementation actually correct?

Your implementation of `listToLL` is correct. I'm not sure I understand what you mean with the rest of this question. Your function **does** use the linked list data type, because it uses the constructors `Nil` and `Cons`.

> I'm very confused by the need for ref in the second join function at all. When I handle a linked list, do I expect that I handle a reference or do I handle the entire Cons structure that contains the reference from within?

Your confusion here is very natural. I remember I became very confused by the exact same issue when I first attempted to implement a mutable linked list in SML.

The `join` implementation you provided creates an extra ref to cleanly handle the case where the first list is empty, because the helper function `joining` operates on objects of type `'a mlist ref` rather than `'a mlist`. It is possible to avoid creating this extra ref, however. Here's how I would do it:

```
(* find the last ref of a linked list *)
fun getLast mlp =
  case !mlp of
    Nil => mlp
  | Cons (_, mlp') => getLast mlp'

fun join (mlpx, mlpy) =
  case mlpx of
    Nil => mlpy
  | Cons (_, mlp) => (getLast mlp := mlpy; mlpx)
```

Answer (score 1):

> convert a list to a singly linked list

Lists in SML are already implemented as linked lists.

When you define a data type like

```
datatype 'a mylist = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a mylist
```

you're creating a type that is isomorphic to the built-in *'a list* type with `[]` (`nil`) and `::` (*cons*).

It seems that your attempt is rather at how to make a *mutable* linked list using references.

> I want to avoid making the linked list into a lazy list

As Sam Westrick pointed out, lazy lists are typically made using closures:

```
datatype 'a lazylist = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazylist)
```

*Edit:* See his [example of suspensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46997808/1031831) [stackoverflow.com] for more details.

> not sure if doubly linked lists are possible anyway

Both mutable linked lists and doubly linked lists are possible using references, but I wouldn't recommend this approach in SML. If you need to traverse a list forwards and backwards, or if you need to update it underway, you can do so purely functionally using ***zippers***:

- Original article: [Huet, 1997](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/edu/seminare/2005/advanced-fp/docs/huet-zipper.pdf) [www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de]
- Tutorial: [Learn You A Haskell: Zippers](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers) [learnyouahaskell.com]

The original article has examples in OCaml and the LYAH chapter has examples in Haskell.

I'd like to see some good examples in Standard ML, but I haven't found any.

Comment: Just a note on laziness, for those who are curious (Simon, I'm guessing you probably just omitted this for brevity): typically, lazy evaluation guarantees that the expression is evaluated at most once. So, while it is *possible* to implement laziness with a function (namely, the memoization function), the function type itself doesn't provide this guarantee. For example, in this definition of lazylists, simply wrapping the tail of the list in `fn () => ...` won't be "lazy".